# how to create a custom shape like half circle without before after?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a shape with div like the below images

[image: round half shape]

I have tried to do it with border and box-shadow but unable to get the exact shape.
The dot in the starting is not a problem, the only thing is the exact arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is fairly similar, you can play with `height` and `width` to achieve the desired size.

You can also adjust the `border-radius`, the last two values to get the exact shape you want - 0% 0% **85%** **85%**.

If it conflicts with other content because of its size then using `absolute` on it would fix that issue as well.

```css
div {
   width: 480px;
   height: 300px;
   border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 85% 85%;
   border: 10px solid #000;
   border-top: 10px solid transparent;
   border-right: 10px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```